# Passing PHP parameter to WCF - loosing string values - loosing all values

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, wcf, parameters

I am having trouble getting my PHP application to correctly pass parameters to my .NET 4.0 WCF Service.
Here is the service code:

```
[OperationBehavior(ReleaseInstanceMode = ReleaseInstanceMode.AfterCall)]
int ICatalogService.CalculatePercentComplete(CoursePercentParam cpp)
{
     string courseID = cpp.Course;
     int mediaIndex = cpp.MediaIndex;
     double position = cpp.Position;

     return ((ICatalogService)this).CalculateCoursePercentComplete(courseID, mediaIndex, position);
}
```

and the CoursePercentParam class:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "Somenamespace.Core.1.0")]
public class CoursePercentParam
{
    string course;
    int mediaindex;
    double position;
    public CoursePercentParam()
    {
    }
    public CoursePercentParam(CoursePercentParam cpp)
        : this()
    {
        this.Course = cpp.Course;
        this.MediaIndex = cpp.MediaIndex;
        this.Position = cpp.Position;
    }

    public string Course { get { return this.course; } set { this.course = value; } }
    public int MediaIndex { get { return this.mediaindex; } set { this.mediaindex = value; } }
    public double Position { get { return this.position; } set { this.position = value; } }
}
```

Note that there are several other places in the code where I can call to this service without trouble.  - works as expected.  The communications between the web application and the WCF service is working.  Just this one call does not get the parameters correctly.

Following is the PHP code that calls it:

```
$getPercentComplete_obj->cpp = array('Course' => $showcurrentcourse->CourseIdentifier, 'MediaIndex' => $mediaIndex, 'Position' => $position);
$getPercentComplete_res = $courseService->CalculatePercentComplete($getPercentComplete_obj);
$percentComplete = $getPercentComplete_res->CalculatePercentCompleteResult;
```

Here are the printed parameters from the PHP application:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [cpp] => Array
        (
            [Course] => BI-0310
            [MediaIndex] => 5
            [Position] => 1203.234
        )

)
stdClass Object
(
    [CalculatePercentCompleteResult] => -1
)
```

As you see here, in the PHP application the data for the parameter is present.
Been looking at this for many hours, cannot seem to find the problem.

FYI: the following is the method that is called by this method above.  I had tried this too using the `$param_obj->courseID = $courseID` for the individual parameters and the string parameter always came across as empty.  That is why I created the method that takes the "CoursePercentParam" class.
Anyway, here is that code:

```
    [OperationBehavior(ReleaseInstanceMode = ReleaseInstanceMode.AfterCall)]
    int ICatalogService.CalculateCoursePercentComplete(string courseID, int mediaIndex, double position)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("courseID=>'{0}', mediaIndex=>'{1}', position=>'{2}'",
            courseID, mediaIndex, position);

        Course course = ((ICatalogService)this).GetCourse(courseID);
        if (null == course)
            return -1;

        double current = ((ICatalogService)this).CalculateCourseProgress(courseID, mediaIndex, position);
        double total = ((ICatalogService)this).GetCourseLength(course);

        int percent = (int)((current / total) * 100);
        Trace.TraceInformation("Percent Complete: {0}", percent);
        return percent;
    }
```

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you,
Jim

Comment: If you're going to vote to close, please comment why. This looks like a decent question to me.

Comment: create a working wcf client for the service and compare the soap it sends (via fiddler or wcf logging) to the one php sends

Comment: For the method CalculatePercentComplete, the properties of the CourseCompleteParams only needed the [DataMember].
This does not explain the behavior where the string parameter of the CalculateCoursePercentComplete is empty when it arrives at the WCF service.  Still looking.